# MongoDB : getting list of values by using Group

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called `contract` and I would like to `group using "a_id"`

```
{
 a_id: 1,
 "name": "n1"
}
{
 a_id: 2,
 "name": "n2"
}
{
 a_id: 1,
 "name": "n3"
}
{
 a_id: 1,
 "name": "n4"
}
{
 a_id: 2,
 "name": "n5"
}
```

I want to `group by "a_id"` to show me the list of names associated.

```
{
 a_id: 1,
 values: ["n1", "n3", "n4"]
}
{
 a_id: 2,
 values: ["n2", "n5"]
}
```

**My code:**

```
db.contract.group({ 
      key:{a_id: 1}, 
      initial: {v: ''}, 
      reduce: function(doc, obj){ 
            v = v + " " + obj.name
      } 
});
```

**My Output:**

```
{
        "a_id" : 1,
        "v" : ""
    },
    {
        "asset_id" : 2,
        "v" : ""
    }
```

This doesn't return the list of values, but **mongd logs** shows me list of names, How can I correct this?

**Fixed**

```
db.contract.group({
   key:{a_id: 1}, 
   initial: {v: []}, 
   reduce: function(obj, prev){ 
      prev.v.push(obj.name)
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed**

```
db.contract.group({
   key:{a_id: 1}, 
   initial: {v: []}, 
   reduce: function(obj, prev){ 
      prev.v.push(obj.name)
   }
});
```

Answer (score 14):

You could also use [MongoDB's aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/):

The following will work exactly the same:

```
db.contract.aggregate({$group: { '_id': '$a_id', 'name': { $push: '$name'}}})
```

The following will put every unique value only once in the result set (in case there are duplicated names per 'a_id'):

```
db.contract.aggregate({$group: { '_id': '$a_id', 'name': { $addToSet: '$name'}}})
```